# Possible to grant certain powers to address?

Tags: safe-core

Is it possible to grant certain powers to an address with a safe, for example only swap execution is allowed via 1inch? Is there a module for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure your Safe to behave according to your own business logic by building your own [Safe Module](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/modules). You can then configure with detail what powers to grant to certain addresses for your Safe.

Hope it helps,
Louis